# Regex replace names of methods

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to replace all occurrences of names within a given string. I'm using regex, since a simple substring match won't work in this case and I need to match full words.

My problem is that I can only match words before and after blanks. But for example I cannot replace a string when it's followed by a blank, like:

```
toReplace()
```

with:
theReplacement()

My regex replace method looks like this:

```
void replaceWord(std::string &str, const std::string& search, const std::string& replace)
{
    // Regular expression to match words beginning with 'search'
    //    std::regex e ("(\\b("+search+"))([^,. ]*)");
    //    std::regex e ("(\\b("+search+"))\\b)");
    std::regex e("(\\b("+search+"))([^,.()<>{} ]*)");
    str = std::regex_replace(str,e,replace) ;
}
```

How should the regex look like in order to ignore leading and trailing non-alphanumericals?

Comment: Could you please add some test cases that show what the program does incorrectly, and what it should do instead?

Comment: `std::regex e("(\\b("+search+")\\b)");`

Comment: @Eljay I've tried that (see commented code above). It doesn't work for cases like this: https://ideone.com/iMFKfL

Comment: @benjist • it worked on my machine, where `\\b` correctly broke only on a word boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to

- Escape all special characters in the regex pattern with `std::regex_replace(search, std::regex(R"([.^$|{}()[\]*+?/\\])"), std::string(R"(\$&)"))`
- Escape all special chars in the replacement pattern with `std::regex_replace(replace, std::regex("[$]"), std::string("$$$$"))` (that is in case you replace with literal `$1` text, `$` can be set with `$$`, so to replace with a double `$`, we need `$$$$` in the replacement here)
- Wrap your search pattern with **unambiguous word boundaries**, i.e. `"(\\W|^)("+search+")(?!\\w)`
- When you replace, add `$1` at the start of the replacement pattern to keep the whitespace (if it is matched and captured into the first group with the `(\W|^)` pattern).

See [C++ sample code](https://ideone.com/YLmOSM):

```
std::string replaceWord(std::string &str, std::string& search, std::string& replace)
{
    // Escape the literal regex pattern
    search = std::regex_replace(search, std::regex(R"([.^$|{}()[\]*+?/\\])"), std::string(R"(\$&)"));
    // Escape the literal replacement pattern
    replace = std::regex_replace(replace, std::regex("[$]"), std::string("$$$$"));
    std::regex e("(\\W|^)("+search+")(?!\\w)");
    return std::regex_replace(str, e, std::string("$1") + replace);
}
```

Then,

```
std::string text("String toReplace()");
std::string s("toReplace()");
std::string r("theReplacement()");
std::cout << replaceWord(text, s, r);   
// => String theReplacement()
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Though it does not work when trying to match a word (without brackets), and when there are non-alpha characters before it. I've made an example: https://ideone.com/iMFKfL

Comment: @benjist Then use ***unambiguous word boundaries*** rather than whitespace boundaries. See [this C++ demo](https://ideone.com/sEzHCX).